YAML only first occurrence of sequence when anchored item is used
Please consider the following YAML file. This is a simplified model but acts the same as my issue.
I want to prepare the template Param which can be reused in multiple records. First one is template and the second one is record that I want to expand with a base params.
Params: &base
    - A: "a"
      B: "b"
      C: 1

    - A: "a"
      B: "bb"
      C: 2
      
Params:
    - <<: *base
    - A: "a"
      B: "bbb"
      C: 3

    - A: "a"
      B: "bbbb"
      C: 4

Simplified python code which handles yaml file. Python 3.10.
import yaml

def load_config(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

config = load_config('input.yml')
print(config)

Which is resolved as follows.
{'Params': [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 1}, {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bbb', 'C': 3}, {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bbbb', 'C': 4}]}

Second item of base sequence with C: 2 is skipped.
I tried multiple things with no result. The closest thing I got is to anchor each item of sequence individually like in the example below:
Params:
    - &param1
      A: "a"
      B: "b"
      C: 1

    - &param2
      A: "a"
      B: "bb"
      C: 2
      
Params:
    - <<: *param1
    - <<: *param2
    - A: "a"
      B: "bbb"
      C: 3

    - A: "a"
      B: "bbbb"
      C: 4

Which is in fact:
{'Params': [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 1}, {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bb', 'C': 2}, {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bbb', 'C': 3}, {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bbbb', 'C': 4}]}

But it forces to add one line in record per one item in template.
The goal is to add just one line (like "- <<: *base" or something) to the records to expand it with all base params items.
Does anyone know how to fix that?
Tried to use a anchored base params to exapand record with all base params but "- <<: *base" use only first occurence of sequence.

<< is a special merge key, adding key and value, if not already in the mapping. You have no other keys in the mappings that are the first and second element of the sequence that is the value for key Param. Is that on purpose?

Please note that the officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents, has been .yaml since at least September 2006 (two thousand and six).

The anchor base includes all elements from the first Param, but you are merging them with merge key <<:

If the value associated with the merge key is a sequence, then this
sequence is expected to contain mapping nodes and each of these nodes
is merged in turn according to its order in the sequence. Keys in
mapping nodes earlier in the sequence override keys specified in later
mapping nodes.

This is why keys in the first item from base overrides those of the second one.
As a workaround, YAML developer ingydotnet posted in a GitHub discussion a solution with a custom sequence constructor that, when a child node is a dict and has a special key '<', extends the output sequence with the sequence under the key '<'.
I've simplified the solution for your specific use case as follows:
import yaml

def join(ldr, node):
    l = []
    for e in ldr.construct_sequence(node, deep=True):
        if type(e) is dict and e.get('<', None) is not None:
            l.extend(e['<'])
        else:
            l.append(e)
    return l

yaml.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:seq', join)

so that:
from pprint import pp

pp(yaml.load('''\
Params: &base
    - A: "a"
      B: "b"
      C: 1

    - A: "a"
      B: "bb"
      C: 2

Params:
    - <: *base
    - A: "a"
      B: "bbb"
      C: 3

    - A: "a"
      B: "bbbb"
      C: 4
''', Loader=yaml.FullLoader))

outputs:
{'Params': [{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 1},
            {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bb', 'C': 2},
            {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bbb', 'C': 3},
            {'A': 'a', 'B': 'bbbb', 'C': 4}]}

